# Proper English?: The flange should be at the position 30mm before the focal plane

Tags: grammar

I'm writing a technical note about an optical system. When I explained the position of the flange from the focal plane, I just thought of a sentence:
"The flange should be at the position 30mm before the focal plane." I don't understand the sentence's grammatical structure, although I came up with it.

Firstly, is this proper English? (Grammarly says it's correct.)
Secondly, I don't understand the structure of the sentence. What is the part of speech of "30mm before the focal plane"? Does it work as an adjective to qualify "the position"?

Comment: I would normally just say "The flange should be 30mm before the focal plane." Using "the position" suggests it is a pre-defined position such as a set of holes in the system base, or has been described previously in the instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Firstly, is this proper English? (Grammarly says it's correct.)

It's grammatical but the meaning is a little unclear.

Are you asking the reader to find the flange or to adjust it's position?

Also I would say "in front of" instead of "before" as it has a clearer meaning.  I would only use "before" to discuss order of operations.

> Secondly, I don't understand the structure of the sentence. What is the part of speech of "30mm before the focal plane"? Does it work as an adjective to qualify "the position"?

*adjective clause*, so yes it acts as an adjective.

Comment: Adjust its position. I want to instruct readers to place the flange at the correct position.